# How to change background Paypal buttons on Nextjs13?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js13, paypal-buttons

I can't change the background paypal's buttons. Anyone else has the same problem ? I tried to add an external div and set a background, but  it doesn't change. Is it a nextjs13 issue ? it's possible ?

I can show you the problem :

[image]

This is my code:

```
   <div className="z-20 relative bg-neutral-900">
      <PayPalScriptProvider
        options={{
          'client-id': ************,
          components: 'buttons',
          intent: 'subscription',
          vault: true,
        }}
      >
        <PaypalButton...../>
           

      </PayPalScriptProvider>
    </div>
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: If an element has its own background color set, then putting a wrapper div with a different background color around it of course won't help - on the z-axis, the element is higher than the surrounding wrapper. If you place a red sheet of paper on top of a blue one, the red won't magically turn blue.

Comment: z-index help me for another thing.. The question is how can I set the background. Your comment don't help me.

Comment: _"Your comment don't help me."_ - it wasn't meant to fix your issue, but to explain why what you want is (most likely) _not possible_. (I am guessing that these buttons render inside an iframe from a different origin(?), which means you have no access to them from your site's code using either JS or CSS.)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901261/paypal-react-js-buttons-background-color) to set the background of the container.

For the buttons, PayPal provides a couple of color customizations, like Gold, Blue, Silver, White, and Black.

Comment: For the buttons, but not for the buttons container. I tried that post but it doesn't work